# SharePoint Anonymous Authentication for One IP Only?

Tags: php, sharepoint, curl, sharepoint-2010

Per my other question, it seems like it's not going to be possible to have SharePoint authenticate our Linux server, which is using PHP and curl to download files from the SharePoint web server.

Turning on view-only anonymous authentication should fix this problem, however, we don't want to open it up for the whole web since literally anyone would be able to view all our files if we do that.

Is there a way to make it anonymous, but then white-list only one IP address (the one of our Linux server)? Or filter by MAC address/hostname/something else?  I haven't been able to find anything in the SharePoint docs about doing such a thing.

Comment: Why cannt you use curl against sharepoint again? I have an implementation of curl talking to sharepoint websites behind NTLM. WHat is the authentication method set in Sharepoint?

Comment: It might need some customization of the curl script, I'm not really sure.  We ended up just ditching SharePoint and hosting the images directly so that way you don't need any authentication.